# URL encoding the character @ in query path

Tags: java, rest, http, urlencode

There are places/libraries that seem to consider "@" characters in a URL Path segment as "special character" that should be encoded, and places/libraries that do not.

I am looking to find out what is the correct version.
Example string: "someone@example.com".

- If I go to https://www.urlencoder.org/ , and try to encode the above String I get 
  someone%40example.com
- If I am using org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils I get these results:

  `String s1 = UriUtils.encodePathSegment("someone@example.com", "UTF-8");
  String s2 = UriUtils.encodeQueryParam("someone@example.com", "UTF-8");
  String s3 = UriUtils.encodePath("someone@example.com", "UTF-8");
  System.out.println("----------s1: " + s1);
  System.out.println("----------s2: " + s2);
  System.out.println("----------s3: " + s3);`

...outputs

```
----------s1: someone@example.com
----------s2: someone@example.com
----------s3: someone@example.com
```

- RestEasy-Client v4.0.0.Final does not encode the "@" character in path segments
- WSO2 ESB complains when receiving a Path parameter that contains @ char (well, it can't find the resource at said moment).

Who is right, what should be the correct outcome, should "@" be transformed to "%40" or not?

Answer (score 1):

> There are places/libraries that seem to consider "@" characters in a URL Path segment as "special character" that should be encoded, and places/libraries that do not.

The standard for which characters must be escaped in a path segment is [RFC 3986, Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

```
path          = path-abempty    ; begins with "/" or is empty
              / path-absolute   ; begins with "/" but not "//"
              / path-noscheme   ; begins with a non-colon segment
              / path-rootless   ; begins with a segment
              / path-empty      ; zero characters

path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
path-noscheme = segment-nz-nc *( "/" segment )
path-rootless = segment-nz *( "/" segment )
path-empty    = 0<pchar>
```

Notice that depending on the path production you are using, there are three different flavors of segment

```
segment       = *pchar
segment-nz    = 1*pchar
segment-nz-nc = 1*( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / "@" )
              ; non-zero-length segment without any colon ":"
```

but...

```
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

So `@` is allowed in any path segment.

Is it required?  As far as I can tell, the answer is no -- using the pct-encoded representation instead is permitted when `@` is not serving the role of a delimiter.  There's nothing explicit, but this [observation about unreserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4) is a hint:

> When a URI is dereferenced, the components and subcomponents significant to the scheme-specific dereferencing process (if any) must be parsed and separated before the percent-encoded octets within those components can be safely decoded, as otherwise the data may be mistaken for component delimiters.  The only exception is for percent-encoded octets corresponding to characters in the unreserved set, which can be decoded at any time.  For example, the octet corresponding to the tilde ("~") character is often encoded as "%7E" by older URI processing implementations; the "%7E" can be replaced by "~" without changing its interpretation.

This suggests that pct-encodings of unreserved characters are permitted, even though that's clearly not required.  So that should hold true for other characters after the delimiters have been resolved.

For reference: the unreserved set is pretty much what you would expect.

```
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

Comment: Just to make sure: this answer holds true for the `@` from an URL like `example.com/people/someone@example.com/doSomething` correct?

Comment: Yes.  The place where you need to be careful is before the path segments -- an `@` encoded into the `userinfo` or `host` will likely make a mess.  https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

If you call an url like `login(:password)@url.com`, it will connect you to that endpoint with your credential. So I would not escape them at that point. But if they appear after the `.com`, I would escape them, because they should not be use as a separator.

Comment: no sorry, my bad, the URL is more like `example.com/people/someone@example.com/doSomething`